# Errors building OpenCV 3.2 @ Win7Prof64 with Code:Blocks 16.01/ mingw 4.9.2

Tags: opencv, mingw, codeblocks

After doing CMake (all with default) I open the Code:Block project file
and building gives these errors:

```
        D:\Guido\develop\opencv\sources\modules\highgui\src\window_w32.cpp: In function 'void cvSetModeWindow_W32(const char*, double)':
        D:\Guido\develop\opencv\sources\modules\highgui\src\window_w32.cpp:474:47: error: 'MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST' was not declared in this scope
                     hMonitor = MonitorFromRect(&rect, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);
                                                       ^
        D:\Guido\develop\opencv\sources\modules\highgui\src\window_w32.cpp:474:71: error: 'MonitorFromRect' was not declared in this scope
                     hMonitor = MonitorFromRect(&rect, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);
                                                                               ^
        D:\Guido\develop\opencv\sources\modules\highgui\src\window_w32.cpp: In function 'LRESULT MainWindowProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)':
        D:\Guido\develop\opencv\sources\modules\highgui\src\window_w32.cpp:1377:45: error: 'MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST' was not declared in this scope
                   hMonitor = MonitorFromRect(&rect, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);
                                                     ^
        D:\Guido\develop\opencv\sources\modules\highgui\src\window_w32.cpp:1377:69: error: 'MonitorFromRect' was not declared in this scope
                   hMonitor = MonitorFromRect(&rect, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);
```

... what makes all this more strange:

At the beginning of this file (window_w32.cpp) the symbol _WIN32_IE
is not defined at all (why?).

As I'm new to C:B and OpenCV hints are appreciated.

Edit:
I just found a hint by myself:

http://answers.opencv.org/question/104125/i-am-unable-to-build-opencv-using-mingw-codeblockstotally-a-beginner/

Do I understand this right, that mingw 4.9.2 does not do with recent openCV?
(But 4.9.2 is the compiler that is actually shipped with C:B) ...

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

Despite OpenCV dropped mingw compiler support in 2015
(why that??)
it is well possible to build OpenCV with mingw.

2 modules make problems when building: highgui and ts.

Both seems to have to do with the way mingw handles
windows headers.

For module highgui:
[Error while building OpenCV :: MonitorFromRect was not declared in this scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21103042/error-while-building-opencv-monitorfromrect-was-not-declared-in-this-scope)

For module ts:
https://github.com/google/googletest/issues/893

Why - in heaven's name - so much stumbling stones
on a way to use a freeware toolchain?
No wonder that M$ will smother everything.
It has to be convenient to use.
If I need a car to do my work, I want to use the car.
Not have to build ("and to understand, that's important!") it.
SCNR.