# I included <winuser.h>, but compiler throws "was not declared" at MonitorFromWindow

Tags: c++, winapi

There is already a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20709016/why-is-monitorfromwindow-missing-not-declared-c-winapi) about it, but it didn't solve the error. I tried commenting out the if on winuser.h, but it did no effect.

```
// Header
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <winuser.h>

// Cpp
 monitorA = MonitorFromWindow(hwnd, MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY); // Errors
    GetMonitorInfo(monitorA, &monitorAInfo); // No error
```

error: 'MonitorFromWindow' was not declared in this scope

error: 'MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY' was not declared in this scope

Also, I am using Code::blocks with gcc compiler.

Comment: possible because `WINVER < 0x0500` in your case

Comment: I commented out the if statement on winuser and it had the same effect, not working.

Comment: you need not edit windows headers but define `WINVER` (however you  have very very old windows. h or not from sdk)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your copy of `<winuser.h>` actually supports `MonitorFromWindow()`, then make sure that you have `WINVER` set to `0x0500` or higher to enable `MonitorFromWindow()`. See the following for more details:

[Using the Windows Headers: Setting WINVER or _WIN32_WINNT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/using-the-windows-headers#setting-winver-or-_win32_winnt)

[Update WINVER and _WIN32_WINNT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/modifying-winver-and-win32-winnt?view=vs-2019)

[What's the difference between WINVER, _WIN32_WINNT, _WIN32_WINDOWS, and _WIN32_IE?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070411-00/?p=27283)

Comment: I had tried this before and didn't work, but now it works. I think I didn't place the #define before the #include. Thank you.

Comment: You aren't meant to `#include <winuser.h>` to begin with. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-monitorfromwindow) is quite clear on this.